# Verification of Solution for Finding Minimum and Maximum of a Function in a Given Region

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, extreme-value-analysis

I want to find the minimum and maximum values of the function $f(x, y) = \ln(1 + 9x^2 + 4y^2)$ within the region $1 \leq \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} \leq 4$. My solution steps are as follows:

1. Calculated the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to $x$ and $y$.
2. Found the critical points by solving the system of equations $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$.
3. Evaluated the function at the critical point (0, 0)

I obtained the following result:

- Absolute Minimum: 0 (at the critical point (0, 0)).

Could you please confirm if my solution is correct or if there is any error in my approach? I appreciate your help in verifying my work.

Comment: I am afraid $(0,0)$ is not in your region.

Comment: @WishYouTheBest You're right! because $(0,0)$ verifies $\frac{0^2}{4} + \frac{0^2}{9} < 4$ but does not verify that it is greater than $1$. I was careless!

Now I'm a little lost, I can't find other candidates for extremes

Comment: Maybe use Lagrange lagrange multiplier method. You now know there are no extremals inside of your region, so look in the  boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region
$$D=\Big \{(x,y):1 \leq \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} \leq 4\Big\}$$
is a compact set and therefore the differentiable function $f$ has minimum and maximum values in $D$.

You are right, $f$ has a unique critical point at $(0,0)$, but $(0,0)\not\in D$ This fact implies that the minimum points and the maximum points stay on the boundary of $D$ which is the union of two ellipses $E_1$ and $E_4$ with
$$E_r=\Big \{(x,y):\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} =r\Big\}.$$

Notice that along any ellipse $E_r$ with $r\geq 0$, the function $f$ is constant:
$$\ln(1 + 9x^2 + 4y^2)= \ln\Big(1 + 36\Big(\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9}\Big)\Big)=\ln(1 + 36r)$$
which is increasing with respect to $r$.
Hence the minimum value of $f$ is attained along $E_1$ where $f$ is identically equal to $\ln(37)$. Similarly, the maximum value of $f$ is attained along $E_4$ where $f$ is identically equal to $\ln(145)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I always evaluate the region in the function to get the candidate extremes of $f$ restricted to the region?

Comment: @Ayesca If the restriction is difficult to evaluate you may use the method of Lagrange multipliers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Example_1

Comment: thank you so much! you are great!